# Making a php OAuth request to Discord

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, discord

Been struggling for a while. Trying to get my token from discord.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$code = '';
$code = $_GET['code'];

if(isset($code)){

$postData = array(
    'code' => $code,
    'client_id' => "[omitted]",
    'client_secret' => '[omitted]',
    'redirect_uri' => '[omitted]'
);

// Create the context for the request
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        // http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => $postData,
                'header' => "Authorization: Bot [omitted]\r\n".
        "Content-Length: ".strlen($postData)."\r\n",
    )
));

// Send the request
$response = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize', FALSE, $context);

echo $response;

} else {
    echo '<a href="https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=[omitted]&scope=identify%20guilds&client_id=[omitted]">Login</a>';
}
```

I keep getting the error

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required in /index.php on line 27

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible strlen is failing on an array? I've seen other people use something like

```
$postData = http_build_query(array('foo'=>'bar'))
```

to transform an array into something they can use in a query.